# Using window.open in gridview hyperplink

Tags: gridview, hyperlink, window

I have a gridview in which I have a column and opening a page through query string. The Column code is here:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="LCNumber" Target="_blank"
                     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="LCDocs.aspx?LCNumber={0}"
                     Text="View" >
     <ItemStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" />
 </asp:HyperLinkField>
```

The problem is that I when click on view, it opens the new tab while I have to open a new window with custom height and width with custom position. What is the solution to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `<a>` tag instead of `<asp:hyperlink>` and replace your hyperlink like below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="PartnerName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a onclick="window.open('LCDocs.aspx?LCNumber=<# Eval("LCNumber")','','width=200,height=100')" id="alink" runat="server" > </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you want to change `{0}`, you can change it via code behind.

Comment: Sir Where is the `DataNavigateUrlFields="LCNumber"` part coz query string is returnin gnothig

Comment: `<a onclick=<%# "window.open('LCDocs.aspx?LCNumber="+<# Eval("LCNumber").ToString()+",'','width=200,height=100'")' id="alink" runat="server" > </a>`  try this

Comment: `<ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Eval("BANK") %>' NavigateUrl=<%# Eval("LCNumber", "javascript:window.open('LCDocs.aspx?LCNumber={0}','popWindow','height=500,resizable=yes,width=500')")%> runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>` what about this

Comment: Can U Please Tell me can i set the window property always on top

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

onblur = function() {
setTimeout('self.focus()',100);
}

</script> add this script in your pop up window

Comment: Sir What time Unit is being used becuase it getting much time to focus

Answer (score 0):

This is my code work with me:

```
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
        function popUp(SERVIC_CODE) {
            strOpen = "CustomerStatmentDetails.aspx?SERVIC_CODE=" + SERVIC_CODE;
            window.open(strOpen, 'popWindow', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=350,height=500,left = 545,top = 200');
    }
    </script>   


<ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton11" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text='<%# Eval("SERVIC_CODE") %>'  OnClientClick='<%# Eval("SERVIC_CODE","javascript: return popUp({0})") %>'  ></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvDemo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#" onclick='openWindow("<%# Eval("Code") %>");'>View Details</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(code) {
        window.open('page.aspx?Code=' + code, 'open_window', ' width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
    }
</script>
```